# Regex match sequence more than once

Tags: regex

How come for something that simple I can't find an answer after looking one hour in the internet?

I have this sentence:

```
HeLLo woRLd HOw are YoU
```

I want to capture all groups that consist of two following capital letters

```
[A-Z]{2}
```

The regex above works but capture only `LL` (the first two capital letters) while I want `LL` in one group and in the other groups also `RL` `HO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most regular expression engines expose some way to make your expression *global*. This means that your expression will applied multiple times. This *global* flag is usually denoted with the `/g` marker at the end of your expression. [This](https://regex101.com/r/fE1oR6/1) is your regular expression without the `/g` flag, while [this](https://regex101.com/r/fE1oR6/2) is what happens when you apply said flag.

Different languages expose such functionality differently, in C# for instance, this is done through the `Regex.Matches` syntax. In Java, you use `while(matcher.find())`, which keeps providing sub strings which match the pattern provided.

EDIT: I am not a Python person, but judging from the example available [here](http://runnable.com/UqV9JYh03AFGAACS/how-to-use-findall-finditer-split-sub-and-subn-in-regular-expressions-in-python-for-regex), you could do something like so:

```
it = re.finditer(r"[A-Z]{2}", "HeLLo woRLd HOw are YoU")
for match in it:
    print "'{g}' was found between the indices {s}".format(g=match.group(), s=match.span())
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** have multiple groups in this case, but you *can* have multiple matches. Add the global flag to your regex and use a method to match the regex.

For javscript, it would be `/[A-Z]{2}/g`.
The method most probably returns an Array of matches, and you can use index to access them.

Comment: Thanks. And in python how do i do it?